# Unable to place figures side by side using subcaption

Tags: subcaption, sidebyside

I am fairly inexperienced in Overleaf and I want to place two figures side by side, I tried the subcaption package. Here is the part of the latex code I used for this

```
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{figure}  
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{image1.eps}
        \caption{Picture 1}
        \label{fig:1}  
    \end{subfigure}   

   \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{image2.eps}
        \caption{Picture 2}
        \label{fig:2}   
   \end{subfigure} 
\end{figure}
```

But I get the output in which the images are placed one below the other. AlsoI get some stray text [b]0.4 from the code and I would like them to be sub labelled 3.6 a) & 3.6 b) instead of Figure 3.6, Figure 3.7 and have a main caption.

Thanks for the help!

[image: Output]

Edit:
I have now added the MWE.

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu]{nag}
\documentclass{memoir}
\newsubfloat{figure}
\newsubfloat{table}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \subcaption{Picture 1}
    \label{fig:1}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \subcaption{Picture 2}
    \label{fig:2}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Main Figure}
  \label{Main figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. To stop getting the line break between the `subfigure` environments, don't leave blanks lines between them. In addition, you should change both instances of `[width=0.4\textwidth]` to `[width=1\textwidth]`, and you should place an `\hfill` directive immediately after the end of the first `subfigure` environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cause that you obtain one image below other is empty line between sub figures as already mentioned @Mensch in his answer, however you need to decide first, which package you will use for subfigures. `memoir` has own mechanism, `subfigure` is obsolete and not compatible with `subcaption`. I suggest you to stick with latter one:

```
%\RequirePackage[l2tabu]{nag}
\documentclass{memoir}
%\newsubfloat{figure}
%\newsubfloat{table}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Picture 1}
    \label{fig:1}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Picture 2}
    \label{fig:2}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Main Figure}
  \label{Main figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Because you gave us no [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) (please add it in you next question!) I have a little bit to guess.

Please see that I used package `showframe` to visualize typing area and margins.
Please see I used image `example-image-a` and `-b` from package `mwe` (must be installed but not called) ...

Now have a look to a part of the corrected code:

```
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth} % <==============================
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a} % <=============
    \caption{Picture 1}
    \label{fig:1}  
  \end{subfigure}
```

I used `0.45\textwidth` to get a smaller white space between the two images. This definition defined a new textwidth for the following

```
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
```

To make sure the image uses the new complete available textwith use option `[width=\textwidth]` as shown above.

Command `\hfill` adds a white space between the two images as available to fill the line. Note that you have to delete all blank lines between the two `subfigure` environments! (Blank line = new paragraph in LaTeX)

Please see the following complete mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showframe} % <==============================================
\usepackage{graphicx} % <===============================================
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}  
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth} % <==============================
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a} % <=============
    \caption{Picture 1}
    \label{fig:1}  
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill % <============================================================
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth} % <==============================
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b} % <=============
    \caption{Picture 2}
    \label{fig:2}   
   \end{subfigure} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I tried the options suggested in the answers but  the problem still seems to persist. I have now added an MWE.

Comment: @ChandramouliSanthanam Well, the culprit is `\newsubfloat{figure}`, please comment it out.

Comment: Commented out \newsubfloat{figure} and \usepackage{subfigure} and it works now :)